# Forcing Touches to Multiple Views

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch, gestures, touchesbegan

I have two overlapping custom views that need to both receive touch events (e.g. touchesBegan and touchesMoved). However I can only get one of the Views (the top one) to receive the events. I have tried forwarding the events from one view to the other view using:

[otherView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

but this does not always work.

I need the touch events to be sent to the two views simultaneously. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you also forwarding the touchesBegan, and other touch related methods you have been intercepting? Have you been calling super?

Comment: how do you mean calling super?

Comment: Intead of [otherView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]; use [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intercept a touch, you should usually call `[super methodYouAreIntercepting]` at the end of the method, if you still want the touch to go through to the next layer. If you do this, and the two views are directly on top of each other, then you don't need to manually forward the touches the way you have been doing. because your comment above suggests that you haven't been calling super in the method, I bet this will solve your issue.

Comment: SOLVED: I was using self.nextResponder which was doing the same thing as calling super. However, I made a cock-up with copying and pasting. I was essentially forwarding all the touches Begand, Ended, Moved etc all to the touchesBegan function. It's working perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: Calling [super touchesBegan:withEvent:] does not work. If it did, a plain old UIView would pass touch events through by default, which it doesn't.